# share a file created with DocumentFile.createFile

Tags: android

I have an app that downloads files to folder selected by the user.

1. I get access to the folder using :

   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION|Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
   startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_PICK_FOLDER_TO_DOWNLOAD);
2. create the downloaded file with

   DocumentFile newFile = destDir.createFile(mime, file.getFileName());
3. I need to share the file. For example if this is a text file, pdf or word doc user can open it in the appropriate app.

File URI seems pretty strange:

"content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3Amy_logs/document/primary%3Amy_logs%2Fford-f-150-raptor-2019-491746%20(1).jpg"

But it is a file created with createFile and I am able to write the contents.

I am not sure FileProvider can help as the dest folder is any folder on the device.

I am not sure is there anyway to share that URI with any other app?

Thank you very much!
V

Comment: "File URI seems pretty strange" -- that seems fairly typical. Bear in mind that it does not have to represent a file on the filesystem, just as `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71236882/share-a-file-created-with-documentfile-createfile` does not have to represent a file on the filesystem. "is there anyway to share that URI with any other app?" -- that `Uri` should work with `ShareCompat.IntentBuilder`, if that is what you are asking.

Comment: Hello,
This doesn't help, same issue

Comment: You can just use the uri for that content scheme to share your file. (You can not even use FileProvider for a content scheme). Better show your code. (And put it in a nice code block please. Which you could have done too with your other code. Your post is a mess).

Comment: "This doesn't help, same issue" -- you have not explained what the issue is.